# print the name of a key in dictionary which has lowest value in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary:

```
dic={'a':'17','b':'9','c':'11'}
```

I want to find the lowest value in this dictionary and show the KEY name of that value 
in the example above, I want the name : `b`

Comment: pleas look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do:

```
dic={'a':'17','b':'9','c':'11'}
min(dic.items(), key=lambda item: int(item[1]))[0]
```

Result:

```
b
```

This works by taking all the "items", which are the key-value pairs:

```
[('a', '17'), ('c', '11'), ('b', '9')]
```

We then use the [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) function to find the one with the minimum value:

```
('b', '9')
```

The items are compared based on the [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) value of the second item in each tuple by the `key` function:

```
lambda item: int(item[1])
```

Once we have that item `('b', '9')`, we then get the key (the first item in that tuple).

Comment: OP wants `b`. `min(dic, key=lambda k: int(dic[k]))`.

Comment: The values are strings. The OP wants `b` as result --> convert to `int`.

Comment: Whoops, didn't type those as strings.  Fixed.

Comment: thanks man ,  and what if we have 2 keys which have same value (and also lowest values in the dic) ? how can we print multiple key name if the have the lowest value in our dic ?

Comment: That's rather more complicated, and probably deserves a new question.  You can take the result from above, and search the dictionary manually `keys = []; for k, v in dic.items(): if v == dic[result]: keys.append(k)`

Comment: @EhsanKordloo: after `m = min(dic.items(), key=lambda item: int(item[1]))[1]`; you can use list comprehension `[x for x in dic.items() if x[1] == m]` or `filter((lambda x: x[1] == m), dic.items())`.

Answer (score 3):

```
k = {'a':'17', 'b':'9', 'c':'11'}
print sorted(k, key=lambda x:int(k[x]))[0]
```

Output: `b`

or

```
print min(k, key=lambda x:int(k.get(x)))
```

Comment: thanks so , which one is faster if you have a huge items in your dictionary?

Comment: @EhsanKordloo the `min` one